# AngularJS, ui.Bootstrap, disable some specific keyboard support for datepicker component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker, angularjs-bootstrap

I have to do a simple datepicker, I override the custom day.tpl.html, and I don't want to show the month.html when the ctrl + up key is press after the pop up is open.
So, I will like to disable the ctrl + up keyboard, but I think I don't have option to do that. Do I have a way to do this?
Thanks in advance